# How do I override a parent element's width with an implicit child element's width?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to specify the width of a div element to be the width of a child img element contained within. However, this width is implicit depending on the size of the source image.

The first flex item shows the effect I'm trying to achieve, however, I've had to manually set the value of the width to 150px. How can this be achieved dynamically (preferably without javascript)?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <style>
       .flex-item {
        border: 1px solid #30b0b0;
        color: #303030;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
       }
       
       .flex-container {
        border: 1px solid #30b0b0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        list-style: outside none none;
        padding: 5px;
       }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <ul class="flex-container">
       <li class="flex-item">
        <div style="width: 150px; margin: auto;">
         <img height="100px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Metrostation_Mladost_1.JPG/150px-Metrostation_Mladost_1.JPG">
         <p>This text stays within the image</p>
        </div>
       </li>
       <li class="flex-item">
        <div>
         <img height="100px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Metrostation_Mladost_1.JPG/150px-Metrostation_Mladost_1.JPG">
         <p>This text sticks out further than the image</p>
        </div>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think making the image container `display: table` and giving the caption the style `display: table-cell; caption-side: bottom` should do the trick.

Note, I got some help from this answer:
[Image caption width to same as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979487/image-caption-width-to-same-as-image)

It was image caption functionality you were looking for, I believe!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <style>
       .flex-item {
        border: 1px solid #30b0b0;
        color: #303030;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
       }
       
       .flex-container {
        border: 1px solid #30b0b0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        list-style: outside none none;
        padding: 5px;
       }
              
                .image-group-container {
                  display: table;
                }
              
                .caption {
                  display: table-caption;
                  caption-side: bottom;
                }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <ul class="flex-container">
       <li class="flex-item">
        <div style="width: 150px; margin: auto;">
         <img height="100px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Metrostation_Mladost_1.JPG/150px-Metrostation_Mladost_1.JPG">
         <p>This is in a div with a hard-coded width, so it stays in the proper boundaries.</p>
        </div>
       </li>
       <li class="flex-item">
        <div class="image-group-container">
         <img height="100px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Metrostation_Mladost_1.JPG/150px-Metrostation_Mladost_1.JPG">
         <p class="caption">This text also stays within image without hard-coding the width.</p>
        </div>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try to remove style "width: 150px" from the div and you'll see that your solution doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the second div, not the first one. The div I updated does not have a hard-coded width.

Answer (score 0):

According to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783721/parent-element-take-child-size-in-css) it can't be done in css :(

But if you are interested in the scripted alternatives..

### JavaScript ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f2zfv36c/))

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var flexItems = document.querySelectorAll(".flex-item");
    for (var i = 0, l = flexItems.length; i < l; i++) {
        var flex = flexItems[i];
        var div = flex.children[0];
        var img = div.children[0];
        div.style.width = img.width + "px";
    }
});
```

## jQuery ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t3gxz2jf/))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flex-item").each(function(){
        var flex = $(this);
        var div = flex.find("div");
        var img = div.find("img");
        div.css("width",img.css("width"));
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: From the OP... _"preferably without javascript"_

Comment: That's why I clarified, according to [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783721/parent-element-take-child-size-in-css) it's not possible, hence the *preferably* is revoked and then from me: *if you are interested in the scripted alternatives*..

Comment: I disagree. I believe my answer above works just with only a few lines of CSS.

Comment: I think you mean to say, "According to this it canNOT be done in css". I saw that page previously and wondered if the conclusion was applicable for absolute widths (as with this problem) and not just relative/percentage widths. Good script solutions.

Comment: Yes I meant can't, and @leishman of course when I was writing these I didn't see your answer, very nice :)